# Unable to build react native windows release build

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I tried builing a release appx for sideloading with react native windows but getting following error

```
Error
MSB3073
The command " cd C:\Users<user>\source\repos\appxtest\windows.. react-native bundle --platform windows --entry-file index.js --bundle-output windows/appxtest/Bundle/index.windows.bundle --assets-dest windows/appxtest/Bundle " exited with code 9009
```

When I enable verbose build " Tools > Option> Project and Solution > Built and run, and change "MsBuild project build output verbosity" to "Diagnostic"

I get this log

7>C:\Users\source\repos\appxtest\node_modules\react-native-windows\PropertySheets\Bundle.Common.targets(13,9): error MSB3073: The command "
7>C:\Users\source\repos\appxtest\node_modules\react-native-windows\PropertySheets\Bundle.Common.targets(13,9): error MSB3073: cd C:\Users\naveen\source\repos\appxtest\windows..
7>C:\Users\source\repos\appxtest\node_modules\react-native-windows\PropertySheets\Bundle.Common.targets(13,9): error MSB3073: react-native bundle --platform windows --entry-file index.js --bundle-output windows/appxtest/Bundle/index.windows.bundle --assets-dest windows/appxtest/Bundle
7>C:\Users\source\repos\appxtest\node_modules\react-native-windows\PropertySheets\Bundle.Common.targets(13,9): error MSB3073: " exited with code 9009.

.

I am able to build a successful Debug appx.
Could someone guide me how to build the release appx with react native windows

Answer (score 0):

Install react-native CLI as a global

use this command: npm install –g react-native-cli

Comment: I am trying to build for Windows. How react-native-cli will help?

Comment: Because Visual studio runs the command without using npx prefix that's why command execution fails just try and you good to go.